# Restrict access to login page if the user is already signin in React with JWT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I restrict access to `/login` page (by manually entering the URL) after the user is already signed in?

I can now enter `/login` in the url and the user, even though it is already signed in and on the home page, can navigate to `/login` page.

I am using JWT, so when the user navigates to /login page, the token remains in the `localStorage`.

I've tried a hook in the /login component:

```
const history = useHistory()

useEffect(() => {
    const isToken = localStorage.getItem('user')
    if (isToken && isToken !== 'undefined') {
      history.push('/')
    }
}, [])
```

The token is set like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

Now, when I try to go on the `/login` page, it seems that it wants to redirect, but crashes with:

> TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property
> Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Please tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong

Comment: What do you get if you do console.log(history)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using React Router, I would recommend using a [Redirect](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect). Also, make sure to clear the previous token in local storage when logging out

```
if (token) {
    return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/'}} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `Login` component, you can check whether user exists or not. If so, just redirect it.

> Rendering a `Redirect` will navigate to a new location. The new
> location will override the current location in the history stack, like
> server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {

  const isLoggedIn = window.localStorage.getItem('user');

  if (isLoggedIn) <Redirect to="/" />

  return (
    // login page
  );

};
```